# Why is "AS emp" needed in this query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT TOP 1 salary FROM (    
   SELECT TOP 3 salary     
   FROM employees     
   ORDER BY salary DESC) AS emp  
ORDER BY salary ASC
```

Why is "AS emp" used in the query? The query does not work without using `AS`.

Comment: You need to name your `sub-select` no other go. Which version of Sql Server you are using

Comment: This is called an alias. It gives a name to the derived table used by the outer query.

Comment: using sql server 2005

Comment: Is it mandatory to name your sub-select always .. I do not see it in queries like this --SELECT name FROM world
  WHERE population >
     (SELECT population FROM world
      WHERE name='Romania')

Comment: what you are using is called a Derived Table, which always must have an alias. Your example is called a sub query, which is slightly different. See [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx) for an intro to subqueries.

Comment: Oracle allows to omit the alias (in some cases).

Comment: I just tested this construct with SQL Server 2012 and it works just fine without the ***AS*** and just a bare alias ***emp***. Do you perhaps  have some other object named or aliased as ***emp*** nearby?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you need to alias the subquery. Think of the subquery as creating another table for you to select from and the query trying to reference it.  It might not be exactly what is going on, but it always helps me justify why I have to add the alias at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This requirement is only briefly stated in the [Documentation on the FROM clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx#Anchor_1), `[AS] table_alias`:

> When a **derived table**, rowset or table-valued function, or operator clause (such as PIVOT or UNPIVOT) is used, **the required table_alias** at the end of the clause is the associated table name for all columns, including grouping columns, returned.

So the reason why `AS emp` is used in the query is that SQL Server requires it.

You could also have aliased it without using the `AS` keyword (the `AS` keyword is optional).